# Подсветка синтаксиса

Tags: c#

Хочу спросить может кто-то другие методы подсветки синтаксиса RtBoxa знает? Просто мой меня немного не удовлетворяет: при быстрой работе начинает весь текст закрашивать. Или может  я где-то накосячил?

```
MatchCollection allIp = Regex.Matches(richTextBox1.Text, textBox1.Text);
foreach (Match ip in allIp) {
    richTextBox1.SelectionStart = ip.Index;
    richTextBox1.SelectionLength = ip.Length;
    richTextBox1.SelectionBackColor = Color.Yellow;
}
```

Comment: Что значит "при быстрой работе?" Скорее всего где-то косяк. Приведите пример неправильной работы.

Comment: Ну, этот косяк сильно меня не напрягает.  Хочу ещё спросить: этот способ подсвечивает с учётом регистра. Как сделать без учёта?

Comment: Например, слово сергей в моём примере он подсветит только сергей, а надо: Сергей, ООооСЕРГЕЙддю, короче все варианты в тексте.

Answer (score 3):

Приведенный вами код ищет все вхождения подстроки и меняет их цвет. Если закрашивается весь текст, значит таковы вхождения.

Что регистр не учитывался надо это явно указать при создании регулярного выражения

```
var matches = Regex.Matches(sentence, pattern, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)
```

Здесь третий аргумент (RegexOptions.IgnoreCase) предлагает игнорировать регистр букв.